# Hex value to a XML Element value in Python

Tags: python, xml, hex

I am trying to generate a XML tree using `xml.etree.ElementTree`. A child element holds value of a 32 byte random number in hex. When I try to assign the random number to the element like `random_num.text = randomnumber()`, the below error is thrown,

```
TypeError: cannot serialize
```

Is there a way to assign the hex value to the child `random_num`?

Python version is 3.4

And `random_number()` is the one that generates the random number and converts to hex.

Any help is appreciated.

This is the code snippet that I want to fix. I am not pasting the entire XML Element tree part.

```
import binascii                                                
import os      
import xml.et.ElementTree
def random_number():                                                                                                                                    
 r = os.urandom(32)
 b = binascii.hexlify(r)
 bb = base64.b64encode(b)
 return bb
Number = ET.Element("Number")     
random_num = ET.SubElement(Number, "Random Number")
random_num.text = random_number()
tree.write("somefile.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', method="xml")
```

Comment: Could you provide code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: `Number` is not defined in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the problem. Your `random_number` function works fine. Here is my code that updated an xml text attribute:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import binascii
import base64

testxml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>'''

def random_number(): 
    r = os.urandom(32)
    b = binascii.hexlify(r)
    bb = base64.b64encode(b)
    return bb

et = ET.fromstring(testxml)
for rank in et.iter('rank'):
    rank.text = random_number()
ET.dump(et)
```